# How to redirect to log in page if session is null

Tags: session, yii

I want to redirect to log in page if session is null at application level using Yii framework. It should be applicable to all pages except log in page. Any helps appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it would be to modify the **Controller** base class (*protected/components/Controller.php*). You can add an `init()` function which will get executed on every Controller call, something like:

```
public function init(){
    if(!isset($_SESSION['mysession'])){
        this->redirect("site/login");
    }
}
```

You can access the current Controller with:

```
Yii::app()->controller->id
```

But you cannot access the Action in the init function (usually you could use `Yii::app()->controller->action->id`). The easiest way to do this is probably to check the URL like:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/site/login"){
    // it's the login page
}
```

You might have to edit the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` before comparing if you are working on your localhost in a sub folder, something like:

```
$url = str_replace("/mysubfloder","",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

And then compare with that. Also probably best to check for the *index.php* in the string as well.

I am assuming you are using this for making certain pages not accesible to non logged in users? If that is the case you really should be using `accessRules`. [Read more about that here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your assumption is right. I want to give access to only one page for non logged in users. Let me take a look at access rules

Comment: No problem Akbar :) Here is a pretty good guide - http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/191/implementing-a-user-level-access-system/

Comment: As of now i haven't used much framework classes. I am using plain PHP with some Yii framework classes. If i use Yii framework classes too much, will it adversely affect on Jquery stuffs which i want to do in the Views. Suppose i use `$form->textfield()` for html `input text` can i manipulate that element using jquery?

Comment: You can use jQuery as normal with Yii, it actually has really great jQuery support built in